# How can I route a subdomain to rails app in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a url https://www.openhub.net which is my rails 4.2.7 app. I have a separate subdomain on another system which is https://code.openhub.net/. If you clink on the second link, this will reroute you to a discontinued page. What's hosting the `code.openhub.net` url is going to be decomissioned and will be rerouted to `openhub.net`. So what I'm trying to do is that when someone tries to go to `code.openhub.net` my rails app that has the `openhub.net` will serve a static page. The problem is that I can't conceptualize how this will work. For example, here is a snippet of rails documentation under routing.

> 3.9 Request-Based Constraints
>   You can also constrain a route based on any method on the Request object that returns a String.
>
> You specify a request-based constraint the same way that you specify a
>   segment constraint:

```
get 'photos', to: 'photos#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' }

You can also specify constraints in a block form:

namespace :admin do
  constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

> Request constraints work by calling a method on the Request object
>   with the same name as the hash key and then compare the return value
>   with the hash value. Therefore, constraint values should match the
>   corresponding Request object method return type. For example:
>   constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } will match an api subdomain as
>   expected, however using a symbol constraints: { subdomain: :api } will
>   not, because request.subdomain returns 'api' as a String.

I understand what the document is saying but when I try to put this code into practice, I'm stumped. Here is my `routing.rb` file:

```
get '???', to: '???', constraints: { subdomain: 'code' }
```

I understand that the subdomain constraint portion of the url will be code but will the `get` and `to` be? How do I know will go under get? Do I simply substitute `get code.openhub.net` which will route to a `CodeController#index`? Has anyone tried to do something like this before? From the documentation I see that the request object has an `original_url` method that I can call. Is there perhaps a way I can make use of this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- As a sidenote, I noticed that subdomain is not a property of the request object outlined here [Rails Request Object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
get '/', to: 'code#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'code' }
```

That will route requests to `https://code.openhub.net/` to the the `index` method in your `CodeController`.

However, the URL will still say `https://code.openhub.net/`. If you don't want that, you might try a redirect, like this:

```
get '/', to: redirect('https://www.openhub.net/'), constraints: { subdomain: 'code' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!